# in C++ smart device, I need configure like default output folder the store card, so when I am debugging

Tags: c++, device

In C++ smart device in visual studios, I need  configure like default output folder the store card, so when I am debugging and use the function CreateDirectory the created folders appears into the SD card.

Comment: More descriptive text would be greatly appreciated. Please provide some code and eventually error outputs. Otherwise you won't get any answer. Too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are referring to is called the "Working Directory". This is the directory that the program is run from when debugging so any operations such as creating or modifying files/folders will originate from that directory. In visual studio if you go to the project properties and look under the "Debugging" section there is an entry for "Working Directory". Enter the directory on the SD card that you would like to run the program from in this box.

Comment: Thanks but when I see the properties in my project and I see debugging , it doesnt show working directory instead it shows  the option called remote executable , I am debugging in a smart device project for pda , but I need exactly that , I need set up the working directory as Storage Card so I will able to manage the folders in my pc, I am using the emulator for pda of the visual studios, and I cant manage the created folder in the virtual memory so for that reason I need configure the working directory as storage card , because the emulator allows set the storage card as a folder of my pc

Comment: put this info into the question